# Card picking algorithm using inheritance

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm just learning python and I've cooked up this code that lets me create a card. Such that when I put the numbers in, it spits out the name of the card.

```
class Card(object):
    """ Represents a standard playing card."""

    def __int__(self, suit=0, rank=2):
        self.suit = suit
        self.rank = rank

    suit_names = ['Clubs', 'Diamonds', 'Hearts', 'Spades']
    rank_names = [None, 'Ace', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King']

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s of %s' % (Card.rank_names[self.rank], Card.suit_names[self.suit])

# Here is the legend for the cards: Spades -> 3 Hearts -> 2 Diamonds -> 1 Clubs -> 0
# Jack -> 11  Queen -> 12  King -> 13

Card(2, 11)
```

Now the output should be "Jack of Hearts" because Jack = 11 and Spades = 2.

However I get this error:

> TypeError: object() takes no parameters
>   [Finished in 0.0s with exit code 1]

But `Card` has object defined in the first line, so I don't know what I did wrong.

Any suggestions?

Comment: try `__init__` rather than `__int__`

Comment: It's `__init__`, Renae told you the same 30' ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As Renae noticed, it's `__init__` rather than `__int__`.
2. When you instantiate a class, the only code that is executed is the code inside `__init__`, so you shouldn't expect to see anything on the screen.
3. The code you put in `__str__` is correct, but it's executed in two cases

   a. if you call it directly, `Card(2, 11).__str__()`,

   b. when it's called by a `print` (statement or fuction?), `print Card(2, 11)`.

So test your code like this

```
card = Cards(2,11)
print card
```